RAD Studio 12 Athens - how to unzip an encrypted zip file?
Embarcadero has this example regarding extracting an encrypted zip file:
System.Zip.TZipFile.Extract
...
    std::unique_ptr<TZipFile> myZipFile(new TZipFile);
    myZipFile->OnCreateDecompressStream = OnCreateDecompressStream;
    myZipFile->ExtractAll("../../");
    myZipFile->Close();
...

TStream* __fastcall TForm2::OnCreateDecompressStream(TStream* const InStream, TZipFile* const ZipFile, const TZipHeader &Item, bool IsEncrypted)
{
    try
    {
        if (IsEncrypted)
        {
            // Perform decrypt operation on AInStream. For example, you can use your own implementation of CryptZip or AES-256.
            // return DecryptedStream;
        }
        else
        {
            return InStream;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception &e)
    {
        return InStream;
    }
}

As you can see, there is a massive chunk missing when it comes to decrypting an encrypted zip file. This gives no details as to how to determine which method the zip file was encrypted with so that appropriate decryption can be done.
Are there any examples of the code that should go in this section to decrypt the file?
C++ preferred, but even a Delphi example would be helpful.

See TZipFile with Password Encryption. According to https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT chapter 6.1 and 7.x, the compressed data stream (ie InStream)  begins with a header that further describes the encryption used for the rest of the stream data

Thanks for the information Remy.  I tried that, but it didn't work as the zip file I was loading was encrypted with something other than pkware.  I found I could use Abbrevia to open the zip files and this handled the encryption correctly.  It would be good to know how I can use TZipFile to determine the type of encryption and decrypt accordingly, but Abbrevia is simple to use and less code to write.
